# Is there a way to import a CSV comma delimited file into mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, csv, character-encoding, mysql-workbench

Hi there I am new to web development.

I am trying to import a CSV file into mysql workbench using 'Table Data Import Wizard'. However, I have read my file needs to be a CSV (MS-DOS), or I get the  following error: *Can't analyze file. Please try to change encoding type. If that doesn't help, maybe the file is not: csv, or the file is empty.*

I cannot use a CSV (MS-DOS) as my data contains a lot of different special characters including those from Nordic Europe. When I convert my CSV (comma delimited) to CSV (MS-DOS) the special characters are no longer the same.

Is there a way to import a CSV comma delimited file into mysql workbench? Or is there a better solution to getting my data into the table such as keeping the special characters the same in the MS-DOS file somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSV should work fine. You just need to [`Load Data Infile`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/)

You will likely need to define these settings though

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/discounts.csv' 
INTO TABLE discounts 
-- comma seperated? maybe pipes '|'?
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
-- what surrounds input and is it optional? then add OPTIONALLY before ENCLOSED
ENCLOSED BY '"'
-- what is at the end of files
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
-- how many header rows are there, if any?
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import regular CSVs without an issue, just make sure the encoding matches.

Something like

```
LOAD DATA
    INFILE yourfile.csv
    INTO TABLE tablename
    FIELDS
        TERMINATED BY ','
        ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES
        TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
```

should work. If your CSV doesn't have headers, remove the `ignore 1 lines` line from the code. If your formatting is different, change the enclosing and terminating characters accordingly.

You can look up the exact syntax in the [manual.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)